# How to synchronize the From To date wrapper in Highstock?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Ok. I'm sure this is an easy one for those accustomed to Highstock.

What I basically want to do is synchronize the From and To date input so that when you click on the From input field, not only will the From input change from "Sep 10, 2012" to "2012-09-10" but the To input field will also go from "Sep 12, 2012" to "2012-09-12".

As it is, it's not very customer friendly as the output basically reads "From: '2012-09-10' To: 'Sep 12, 2012'

What I already know is that the change in code would've to take place somewhere after line 15639 within Highstock.src.js (I'm using version 1.1.5). Unfortunately, I'm not very good at modifying Java Script code

Comment: Won't recommend changing the source code directly, there are enough seams to inject code so as to get your use case working

Answer (score 1):

you may want to play with [`rangeSelector.inputDateFormat`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#rangeSelector.inputDateFormat) and [`rangeSelector.inputEditDateFormat`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#rangeSelector.inputEditDateFormat)

The easiest way would be setting both to the same, so immaterial weather it's edit or normal mode, the two box will still show same formatting

```
rangeSelector: {
    inputDateFormat : '%Y-%m-%d',
    rangeSelector.inputEditDateFormat : '%Y-%m-%d'
}
```

Alternatively you can use the `Highcharts.dateFormat(format, time)` method to format the date in the required format and set it into the text boxes

```
var dateImputBoxes=[chart.rangeSelector.leftBox, chart.rangeSelector.rightBox];

function formatBoxes(format) {
    $(dateImputBoxes).each(function() {
        this.value = Highcharts.dateFormat(format, this.HCTime);
    });
}

$(dateImputBoxes).each(function() {
    $(this).focus(function() {
        formatBoxes('%Y-%m-%d');
    });
     $(this).blur(function() {
        formatBoxes('%b %e, %Y');
    });
});
```

[Format Input Date text boxes @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/AVUE9/)

Comment: Thanks. I'll use the first method as a temporary fix while I'm fiddling with jsFiddle some more (or someone else comes up with an even better solution). I'm sure my boss won't mind :)

Comment: @user1682540 let me know if you have trouble understanding some code in the fiddle